# When creating a new big query external table with parquet files on gcs. Showing error

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, parquet

I was trying to create a big query external table with parquet  files on gcs. It's showing a wrong format error.

But using the same files to create a native table works fine. why it must be a native table.

If use a native table, how can I import more data to this table? I don't want to delete and create the table that every time I got new data.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parquet is not currently a [supported data format for federated tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-table-definition). You can repeatedly load more data into the same table as long as you append (instead of overwriting) the current contents.

Comment: Will it be supported in the future?

Comment: You could [file a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187149%2B) and see what the team says.

Comment: You can star and follow the feature request here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70116017

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be supported now, [at least in beta](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage). This only works in us-central1 as far as I can tell.

[Simply select 'External Table' and set 'Parquet' as your file type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8s79.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

The current google documentation might be a bit tricky to understand. It is a two step process, first create definition file and use that as an input to create the table.

Creating the definition file, if you are dealing with unpartitioned folders

```
 bq mkdef \
  --source_format=PARQUET \
  "<path/to/parquet/folder>/*.parquet" > "<definition/file/path>"
```

Otherwise, if you are dealing with hive partitioned table

```
bq mkdef \
  --autodetect \
  --source_format=PARQUET \
  --hive_partitioning_mode=AUTO \
  --hive_partitioning_source_uri_prefix="<path/to/hive/table/folder>" \
  "<path/to/hive/table/folder>/*.parquet" > "<definition/file/path>"
```

> Note: **path/to/hive/table/folder** should not include the partition
>   folder
>
> Eg: If your table is loaded in format
>   **gs://project-name/tablename/year=2009/part-000.parquet**
>
> ```
> bq mkdef \
>       --autodetect \
>       --source_format=PARQUET \
>       --hive_partitioning_mode=AUTO \
>       --hive_partitioning_source_uri_prefix="gs://project-name/tablename" \
>       "gs://project-name/tablename/*.parquet" > "def_file_name"
> ```

Finally, the table can be created from the definition file by

```
bq mk --external_table_definition="<definition/file/path>" "<project_id>:<dataset>.<table_name>"
```

Comment: This is the right answer for a cli as of June 2020. I was getting stuck with bq load (to create a native table). For anyone who wants that instead, here it is:
`bq load --source_format=PARQUET --autodetect --hive_partitioning_mode=AUTO --hive_partitioning_source_uri_prefix=gs://bucket/subdir/ project:dataset:table gs://bucket/subdir/*/file.parquet`